# Pass a css class from controller to a partial view in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple code from controller

```
public ActionResult CreatePage() {

   return PartialView( "APage" );
}
```

and the part of that page `APage` is:

```
<table class="@className">
  <tr>
  ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

In javascript, I want to generate `APage` with different class name (css class name)

```
$.post('CreatePage', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

How to pass in controller function (if I would declare : `public ActionResult CreatePage(string cssClass) { ... }`) the parameter to `PartialView` function ?

Means

I want like:

```
public ActionResult CreatePage( string cssClass ) {

       return PartialView( "APage", cssClass );
    }
```

And I want to use that css class into `APage` view.

For example:

1. If I call

   `$.post('CreatePage', {cssClass: 'aClass' ,function(data) {
     $('.result').html(data);
   });`
2. Then it will call

   ```
   public ActionResult CreatePage( string cssClass ) {

      return PartialView( "APage", cssClass ); //cssClass = 'aClass'
   }
   ```
3. And return the view like

   `<table class="aClass">
       <tr>
       ...
       </tr>
     </table>`

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you change the classname on the client side with javascript?

Comment: Why do you want to change class name?  and how many css classes do you think you have ,if few you can put a simple logic in the view

Comment: I mean do you use Spark or Razor?

Comment: I have no Spark, Only ASP and Razor ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but your example, I think, is already on the right track.

In your partial view, add this at the very top:

```
@model string
```

And then in your partial view, change the table tag definition to

```
<table class="@Model"> <tr> ... </tr> </table>
```

Comment: I knew that but I have already a Model of other type than `string`

Comment: Then modify your model to include the cssClass. Create a `ViewModel` if it doesn't exist at this point. Then construct the ViewModel from your controller action then pass the ViewModel to your partial view. In your partial view, change the @model declaration to the type of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

To extend upon what @rikitikitik said.

You already discovered the [`PartialView(viewName, model)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460161.aspx) method overload, now you just have to extend your current `model` to include the CSS class string. Just add a property called `CssClass` and you will be able to use it in your partial view.

This of course assumes you are using [view models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx) (and thus the [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM)), not "just" models or even database models (handled by for example Entity Framework).

```c#
public class APartialModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ... other properties
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
}
```

```c#
public ActionResult CreatePage( string cssClass ) {

   // Initialize the entire view model for the partial view here
   // This usually means you need to pass in an id and use it to
   // make a database lookup.
   // If it's "too much work", it probably means you
   // need to fix a structural problem.
   APartialModel model = new APartialModel
       {
           Name = "Somehow I already know this value",
           CssClass = cssClass
       };

   return PartialView( "APage", model );
}
```

```html
@model APartialModel

<table class="@Model.CssClass">
  <tr>
  ... for example @Model.Name
  </tr>
</table>
```